# modeling associated models (DRY, KISS, SKINNY CONTROLLER AND FAT MODELS)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, dry

I have two Models:

Server (belongs to a Slave)

Slave (hasMany Servers)

In a Controller I need to get an array with information about a Server/Slave (and some additional informations, like business logic that can't be in Controller).. I thought to create a function in Server Model to build the array, and every field that I need from Slave I would just to call a function like this:

```
Model Server:

// I created this function for code easier to maintain
function getSlaveId($server_id){
    $this->id = $server_id;
    return $this->field('slave_id');
}

// Return the array that I need, with informations from Server and Slave
function getArrayByServerId($server_id){ 
    $slave_id = $this->getSlaveId($server_id);
    return array(
        'slave_name' => $this->Slave->getName($slave_id)
        // some other information that some did not even pull from some table..
    );
 }
```

as you can see, I created a function to pull a field from Server, because if one day that changes, I'll have to change only in one place .. the same goes for the Slave whose I'm thinking of using a function to pull each field too ..

So, the question is: should I to get Slave's info with a function for each field or there is another better way to do? (I need almost whole Slave's table info, except some fields..)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) which will pull the necessary information without complex logic like this. Using the behaviour you could make the request like:

```
$this->Server->find('first', array('conditions'=>array(...), 'contain'=>array('Slave')));
```

This way you don't make your models unnecessary fat (healthy are they :)) and you will take what is required. With [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) you can get specific fields too.

Comment: what if a field name change in Slave table, I will have to change in every call of it, won't I?

Comment: Everything can change, even the function name getSlaveId(). If the database design is planned well, I don't think you should change a name of a column, assuming that you follow the Cake naming convention and also there is feature virtual fields which probably could be used too.